# Use bittorrent to download from China?

Tags: networking, bittorrent, parallel-processing

I have a server in China and a client in Europe and need to download large (50-100 GB) files as quickly as possible. The connections to China are wonky at best and very slow. A way to get around this is making many connections and downloading a file in parallel.

I wonder if this is possible using the bittorrent protocol? As far as I know a single file download from one seeder to one client is a single connection, but are there ways around this? Using several seeding clients on the server perhaps? or several linked receiver clients on the receiver side? What options are there?

Note these are not public files, they only exist at one location and are only to be transferred to one location.

Both computers run Windows.

Update:
Have tried several of @SpiderPig's solutions;

- file.pizza works for smaller files, but chokes on very large files (seems like the web browsers read the entire file into memory)
- aria2 can make multiple connections to the same server for the same file, but once one connection is dropped it's not reconnected so it gets slower and slower over time.
- Catapult did give reasonable download speeds but sometimes it just stops transmitting and won't restart without intervention.

Comment: .I'd probably just try robocopy and tell it to try multiple connections but that depends on what the network connectivity is   I just have so many questions what is at each end? Linux or windows , is there a client in Europe copying from a smb share in China ,protected by a VPN I hope.

Comment: Both computers run windows and the connection is just straight over the internet. I think a VPN is technically just a single connection which would cancel any advantages of multiple connections being run inside it. But I'm no expert at VPN. The important thing is that I get multiple connections over the internet and any solution that provides this is interesting.

Comment: You might not be able to establish a VPN connection to location in China... It's illegeal there, I think. But first things first: what is your idea of a large file?

Comment: Depends on how I choose to packet the data, but the source data is up to perhaps 50-100 GB. It's of course possible to zip it into a lot of smaller parts if needed.

Comment: You could try https://file.pizza/ which works similar to bittorrent. You can also install a simple webserver e.g. the [webserver for chrome](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRq8TCl-jWAhWDMhoKHaPzD9MQFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fweb-server-for-chrome%2Fofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AOvVaw37MqUO7yBo81gh1Cz1IBP4) and then download from that webserver with [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) which can use several connections in parallel. What kind of speeds are you able to get btw.?

Comment: Get someone to put it on a USB stick and use classic mail to have it mailed to you.

Comment: @SpiderPig the file.pizza suggestion was great, by downloading the same file 5 times 5 connections are made and the download speed seemed pretty respectable. What is currently used is FileZilla on a zip divided in 25 MB chunks and that gives between 1 and 10 Mb/s, but many transfers fail and need to be restarted.

Comment: I found some more possible solutions. [Catapult](https://www.catapultsoft.com/) and [WDT](https://github.com/facebook/wdt) . But WDT needs a linux system and you need to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A tracker is needed for all peers to connect to for a updated list of peers. Fortunately, utorrent comes with a built-in tracker function that we can utilize to achieve this

here is a brief article to share torrent privately using build in tracker of utorrent

http://bootstrike.com/Articles/CreateTorrent/

Note : Proceed at your own risk!